# jquery animating searchbar movement

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate

While I can get this to work with absolute values I'd need to get it work with more automatic values.

this be code (still under works, since not even first case aka increasing "margin-right" when its in starting position works):

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{   
var $searchbarWidth = $('.searchform input[type="text"]').outerWidth( );

var $submitbuttonWidth = $('#submitbutton').outerWidth( );

var $searchbar_marginRight=$('.searchform input[type="text"]').css("margin-right");
//set starting position
$('.searchform input[type="text"]').css({"margin-right": -Math.abs($searchbarWidth) + 'px'});

//when hidden
    $('#submitbutton').click(function() {
        if($searchbar_marginRight == -Math.abs($searchbarWidth))
        {
        $('.searchform input[type="text"]').animate({"margin-right": '+=210'});
        }   
    });
    //when shown
    $(document).click(function(){
        if($('.searchform input[type="text"]').css("margin-right")== "60px")
        {
            $('.searchform input[type="text"]').animate({"margin-right": '-=210'});
        }
    });

});
```

Anyone knows what exactly goes wrong in if-clause assuming that's one which fails

Comment: Please add relevant html and jQuery dependency as well in the code.

Comment: please add html also

Comment: issue is not with html or dependency, like said everything works fine long as values are preset, but when trying to automate it starts to fail